# Is it possible to install Android OS on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, android

Just wondering, is it possible to install dual OS on an iPhone 3GS/4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is for iPhone 3G and 3GS, but not for iPhone 4 as it uses a different bootrom. Just google "Android on iPhone 3GS" and click on the first entry, where you'll find instructions on how to do it.

Comment: Bear in mind that performance of 2.3.3 on a 3GS is not very good, apparently GINGERBREAD is optimized for other chips.