# Can we install Android on an iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, android

Does anyone know if we can install Android on an iPhone 4?

I've jailbroken my phone with redsnow, and followed the steps at http://lifehacker.com/5693309/how-to-install-android-on-an-iphone-in-six-easy-steps which teaches you how to install Android on an iPhone.

However when I tried to add the repository http://repo.neonkoala.co.uk into Cydia (step two), I have the error repository not found:

[image]

Does anyone know where is the new website for downloading the repository at http://repo.neonkoala.co.uk?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to install Android OS on an iPhone?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16878/is-it-possible-to-install-android-os-on-an-iphone)

Comment: The question of whether it is possible to install Android on any iOS device (or iPhone) is different than whether it can be installed on an iPhone 4 specifically.

Comment: Although the questions is acceptable.  You can sell the iPhone and buy an android 4.0 compatible phone for less then $50.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is **no**.

At the moment, most of iPhone 4 hardware is unsupported by iBoot. The thing is that iPhone 4 bootrom hasn't been hacked in order to install custom boot loader that will boot Android **and**, as I said before, many of iPhone 4 hardware has no drivers.

Also, iDroid allows you to install only 2.x at the moment. However, I have asked the devs some time ago, they told me that they're working on porting Android 4 to the iPhone 4.

Anyway, until there are a needed bootrom hack (which also leads to untethered jailbreak, pod2g/Chronic can release it soon) and quite enough drivers you won't be able to install android on your phone.

Comment: Do you know how long the wait will be? Like 1 month, 6 months or 2 years?

Comment: The team displaces ETAs so I really have no idea. They also told me that progress is really slow. However, if there will be found some meaningful BootROM bug, they might hurry up (That's just my opinion).

Comment: You can track the status of iDroid and related developments here - http://www.idroidproject.org/wiki/Status